# Error "unused argument (env = environment(f)" in lme4

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to perform an `lmer` in R, from the `lme4` package, but I keep getting the error :

> Error in reformulate(paste0("(", vapply(findbars(f), deparse1, ""), ")"),  :
> unused argument (env = environment(f))".

Any ideas? Example with iris:

```
library(lme4)
lmer(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + (1|iris$Species))
```

(I know this doesn't make much sense intuitively, but as an example)

Comment: The code runs without error on my machine. Have you tried using the `data` argument, i.e. `lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris)` ?

Comment: Yes, and it is still the same... Maybe it's something related with my PC? I run R in ubuntu

Comment: Have you restarted your session and tried running this? I just ran it on my Ubuntu server and it worked fine: R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug/incompatibility between the current (CRAN) version of `lme4`, 1.1-28, and versions of R older than 3.6.0. From the [r-sig-mixed-models mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2022q1/029950.html):

> This is a bug that was recently noted (and fixed in the development
> version) here:
> https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/664
> Running this code snippet
>
> ```r
> assign('reformulate', envir = topenv(),
>                 function(..., env = parent.env) {
>                     f <- base::reformulate(...)
>                     environment(f) <- env
>                     return(f)
>                 })
> ```
>
> might fix the problem.

Alternately, if you have development tools (compilers etc.) installed on your computer, `remotes::install_github("lme4/lme4")` will install the development version (which should also fix the problem).

Or you can install a more recent version of R (which might be the best solution and save you future headaches) — see instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) for installing an up-to-date version of R on Ubuntu.